# android parse string to date - incorrect date

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I've spent a lot of time and I still do not understand why this is happening. In the code below, the time changes correctly, the date is not.

```
String dtAll = mDate + " " + mTime;
Date dat = new Date();

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
try {
    dat = format.parse(dtAll);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.d("dat", String.valueOf(dat));
Log.d("dtAll", dtAll);
```

Results:

```
D/dat: Sun Dec 31 17:24:00 GMT+01:00 2017
D/dtAll: 20/09/2018 17:24
```

Will anyone help me?

Comment: try with lowercase year, `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm`

Comment: It was so obvious ...
the simplest mistakes are the most difficult to notice, ehh. Thank you!

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: thank you for the tip, I will see!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use year in format `yyyy`:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
```

Comment: It was so obvious ... the simplest mistakes are the most difficult to notice, ehh. Thank you!

Comment: great! if works fine, please mark the answer as correct =)